# What are the best practices for floating-point comparisons in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, floating-point

Obviously, float comparison is always tricky. I have a lot of assert-check in my (scientific) code, so very often I have to check for equality of sums to one, and similar issues.

Is there a quick-and easy / best-practice way of performing those checks?

The easiest way I can think of is to build a custom function for fixed tolerance float comparison, but that seems quite ugly to me. I'd prefer a built-in solution, or at least something that is extremely clear and straightforward to understand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's most likely going to have to be a function you write yourself. I use three things pretty constantly for running computational vector tests so to speak:

**Maximum absolute error**

```
return max(abs(result(:) - expected(:))) < tolerance
```

This calculates maximum absolute error point-wise and tells you whether that's less than some tolerance.

**Maximum excessive error count**

```
return sum( (abs(result(:) - expected(:))) < tolerance )
```

This returns the number of points that fall outside your tolerance range. It's also easy to modify to return percentage.

**Root mean squared error**

```
return norm(result(:) - expected(:)) < rmsTolerance
```

Since these and many other criteria exist for comparing arrays of floats, I would suggest writing a function which would accept the calculation result, the expected result, the tolerance and the comparison method. This way you can make your checks very compact, and it's going to be much less ugly than trying to explain what it is that you're doing in comments.

Comment: Using `eps` for tolerance is usually a good idea. Also, R2013a and onward has assertEqual statements within the unit testing framework that will help.

Comment: Indeed, but sometimes it may not be enough, given that you may have lost precision several times in course of some calculations.

Comment: Thanks, eps() sounds like a good idea. I was actually hoping for some kind of assertEqual outside of the unit test framework.

Comment: The formula for the root mean squared error above seems misnamed or wrong, because there is no "mean": the error is not normalized with respect to the number of samples.

Answer (score 11):

Any fixed tolerance will fail if you put in very large or very small numbers. The simplest solution is to use `eps` to get the double precision:

```
abs(A-B)<eps(A)*4
```

The 4 is a totally arbitrary number, which is sufficient in most cases.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know any special built-in solution. Maybe something with using the [eps](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) function?

For example as you probably know this will give False (i.e. `0`) as a result:

```
>> 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3

ans =

     0
```

But with eps you could do the following and the result is as expected:

```
>> (0.1+0.1+0.1) - 0.3  < eps

ans =

     1
```

Comment: You should pass the order of magnitude to `eps`, since `eps(10000)` is larger than `eps(1)`, the default.

Answer (score 1):

Since R2015a, there has been [`ismembertol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html) in MATLAB. This effectively allows you to test for equality with either a default tolerance (1e-12 for `double`; 1e-6 for `single`), or a specified tolerance. For example:

```matlab
find(ismembertol(-0.3:0.1:0.3, 0.1)) % gets the result 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had good experience with [xUnit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846-matlab-xunit-test-framework), a unit test framework for Matlab. After installing it, you can use:

- `assertVectorsAlmostEqual(a,b)` (checks for *normwise* closeness between vectors; configurable absolute/relative tolerance and sane defaults)
- `assertElementsAlmostEqual(a,b)` (same check, but elementwise on every single entry -- so `[1 1e-12]` and `[1 -1e-9]` will compare equal with the former but not with the latter).

They are well-tested, fast to use and clear enough to read. The function names are quite long, but with any decent editor (or the Matlab one) you can write them as `assertV<tab>`.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for your attempt to improve my post, but I would rather stick to the standard English syntax Matlab. See more on my motivation [here](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/504/4405). I will revert your edit. I would suggest you to avoid [similar edits](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23824577/3) in the future, as they are just a matter of style (like changing between British and American spelling), and they might go against the wishes of the original author.

Answer (score -3):

For those who understand both MATLAB and Python (NumPy), it would maybe be useful to check the code of the following Python functions, which do the job:

```python
numpy.allclose(a, b, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08)
numpy.isclose(a, b, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08, equal_nan=False)
```

Comment: This question is regarding MATLAB, not Python `numpy`.  Read the question title and the tags carefully.  Moreover, this is probably not constructive for those who are not familiar with Python and `numpy`, so checking the implementations of these is rather useless.

Comment: My experience is that many people use both matlab and python, so to those people it is useful to do code cross check

Comment: From my experience on StackOverflow, a lot of people who answer MATLAB questions here do not know Python.  I'm probably one of the few here that know both relatively well at the same time, and given my perspective, this answer is not useful.  It's up to you on whether or not you want to leave it, but I'm gonna leave my downvote.  It's not that I don't think your answer is technically correct, but it's because you have placed an answer in a question whose tags are not compatible.

Comment: However, if you **translated** the equivalent `numpy` code into MATLAB, then that is a very useful answer, and I'd be inclined to upvote.  This way, not only do you point out what `numpy` already has, but you're giving us a way to do this in MATLAB.