# Matlab explanation of computational errors

Tags: matlab

In a previous problem, there was the equation:

```
e = 1 – 3*((4/3) – 1)
```

And the is not `0`, but rather:

```
e =2.2204e-16
```

I understand why this occures, for `4/3` cannot be represented exactly.

The closest representation of `4/3` is:

```
1.3333333333333332593184650249895639717578887939453125
```

And after the necessary operations, `e =2.2204e-16` is obtained.

Now, I am having trouble understanding the odd behaviors in these equations involving `e`:

1)

```
 b = 1e-16 + 1 - 1e-16; 

 c = 1e-16 - 1e-16 + 1;
```

Here we expect `b` to equal `c`, but this isn't the case. I know there is something fishy going on with the order of operations and the error, but I don't exactly understand why `b` doesn't equal `c`.

2)

```
sqrt(1e-16 + 1) - 1;
ans=0
```

Now, I suspect when the subtraction is done, and since the operands are nearly equal, there was some sort of cancellation. But I am still a little confused and would appreciate a detailed explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I believe the key is [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html). For instance, `sqrt(1+1e-16)==1`. Using a Taylor series, `sqrt(1+1e-16)~~1+0.5e-16`, but `eps(1)` is more than `2e-16`. So the result of `sqrt(1+1e-16)` is rounded back to exact `1`.

Comment: Time to read about floating point math: http://terminus.sdsu.edu/SDSU/Math541_f2006/Lectures/02/lecture-static.pdf

Answer (score 0):

When working with floating point numbers even in MATLAB it's not accurate when it comes to comparing such values. Assertions for near equality, using tolerance (relative error, absolute error etc.) and so on is what one should do if a specific level of accuracy is required.

Check [Comparing Floating Point Numbers, 2012 Edition](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23824820/1559401). In MATLAB relative error accuracy can be achieved through the [`eps`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) function.