# How would I reorder the real parts of a diagonal matrix along with the corresponding eigenvectors in another matrix?

Tags: matlab, sorting, for-loop, matrix, eigenvalue

I am working on MATLAB problems from my textbook and one of the problems asks me to use the `eig` command in MATLAB, compute the matrices `V` and `D` such that `A = V * D * inv(V)`. Knowing that the first column of `V` corresponds to the first eigenvalue `D(1,1)` and so on, I need to reorder the diagonal entries of `D` so that the real part is increasing down the diagonal and reorder the columns of `V` accordingly so that `A = V * D * inv(V)` still holds. Here's what I have written so far:

```
r = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',1234);
A = r.randn(10,10)+1j*r.randn(10,10);
[V,D] = eig(A);

for tt = 1:9
    if (real(D(tt,tt)) > real(D(tt+1,tt+1)))
        temp = D(tt,tt);
        D(tt,tt) = D(tt+1,tt+1); 
        D(tt+1,tt+1) = temp;
        tempV = V(1,tt);
        V(1,tt) = V(1,tt+1);
        V(1,tt+1) = tempV;
        if (A == V*D*inv(V))
            break
        end
    end
end
```

When I tested it, the diagonal elements of `D` did not change from the original order, I know it might be due to the conditionals I set, but I am not sure what specifically is causing it to not do anything. I also think there might be issues in the way I am reordering the diagonal elements and corresponding eigenvectors. Any feedback or suggestions is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to reorder anything? Please read the documentation to `eig`: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html

Comment: Also note that exact equality comparison is unreasonable. There will always be floating-point rounding errors. `A*V-D*V` should be very small, but will likely not be exactly 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems:

- You need two for-loops for [sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Implementation).
- You are only swapping first element of eigenvectors, use `V(:, tt)` for whole column.
- `V*D*inv(V)` will never be exactly equal to `A` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824577/what-are-the-best-practices-for-floating-point-comparisons-in-matlab)).

To sort eigenvalues by their real parts, try this:

```
clc;
r = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',1234);
n = 10;
A = r.randn(n)+1j*r.randn(n);
[V,D] = eig(A);
d = diag(D, 0); % get eigenvalues in a vector
[~, I] = sort(real(d)); % get index of eigenvalues after sorting
D2 = diag(d(I)); % get sorted eigenvalues as diagonal matrix
V2 = V(:, I); % reorder eigenvectors to match sorted eigenvalues
any(any(abs(A - V2*D2*inv(V2)) > 1e-14)) % test sorted eigenvalues and eigenvectors
```