# In MATLAB, why does arr==el sometimes fail to find element el in array arr?

Tags: arrays, matlab, element, precision, equality

In MATLAB R2016a, suppose that I define the array arr = -0.2:0.1:0.2.  I may then find the location of the value el = 0.1 with the command idx = find(arr==el).  This correctly yields idx = 4.

But now suppose that I define a larger array such as arr = -0.3:0.1:0.3.  If I again try to find the location of the value el = 0.1 with the command idx = find(arr==el), I obtain an empty matrix.  For some reason, MATLAB does not consider the 0.1-like element in arr to be equal to el = 0.1.

Why is this and how can I generate an array for which element-finding operations like the above work reliably?

Comment: “how can I generate an array for which element-finding operations like the above work reliably?” You can’t. Because 0.1 cannot be written exactly in binary. All you can do is improve your element-finding comparison (using a tolerance like in the linked answer) or change your problem so you only store integers in your array.

Comment: The answers of this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824577/what-are-the-best-practices-for-floating-point-comparisons-in-matlab) basically answer my question above.  Note especially the example, 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3, which evaluates to False in MATLAB.  The comparison of 1.2 - 0.2 - 1 == 0 and 1.2 - 1 - 0.2 == 0 is also interesting.

Comment: It's a shame this question is closed, because although all the relevant information is indeed in the linked answer, for the specific case here you can use MATLAB's `ismembertol` to solve your problem, like this:  `find(ismembertol(-0.3:.1:.3, 0.1))`

Comment: @Edric I've added OP's link as an additional duplicate since it relates specifically to options for comparisons, you could add using `ismembertol` as an answer to the duplicate since it's not currently listed.